# Im tryna make a unban with id, this is what i have so far, i tried doing int: id it didnt not work

Tags: discord.py

@client.command(description='Unbans the person mentioned.')
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()

```
member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')
for ban_entry in banned_users:
    user = ban_entry.user
    
    if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
        await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Unbanned: {user.mention}")
```

Comment: pls explain more

Comment: Please edit your question: move the title text to your question body and give your question a shorter title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, you should type hint the `member` argument, which automatically converts it to a `discord.Member` and then just unban it:

```py
@client.command(description='Unbans the person mentioned.') @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True) 
async def unban(ctx, *, member:discord.Member):
    await member.unban() #Unban the member
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Unbanned: {user.mention}")
```

Reference:

- [member.unban()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.unban)

Comment: It doesnt aknowledge anyone, it just says user not found now

Comment: Try mentioning the user/writing their id instead of writing name#0000. Name#0000 should work as well, maybe you have an error with capitalization. @SafwatAbunaja

Comment: i copied and pasted, still no luck